# What is the best/quickest method to upload a very large folder to my Server?

Tags: web-hosting, compression

I have a large directory which I need to upload to a new host's server, but because I have never transferred such a large directory (32GB), I am wondering whether there is something I'm missing.

Now, I am assuming that the best way is to compress it into a zip file, upload to the server and then extract. But for some reason, my zip file is still about 32GB!

I have already attempted to start uploading the files and it has literally been taking about 30 hours to simply upload about 3GB! Obviously this is too long, so I wondered whether there is a better method of doing this?

Comment: if this is a recurring thing, you could sign up for amazon s3 and send them a hard disk with your data ;), or get a better internet connection, but usually upstream bandwidth for non-business internet access is pretty limited, so uploading 32gb could take at least a few days. zipping would descrease size if your data is compressible, like text files, source code etc. it has almost no effect on video and image files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed of upload is determined by your internet connection speed. Try to find different location with faster connection speed. It could be your work, school or internet caffee.

You can test your upload speed here: http://speedtest.net/

Pack everything into large zip file, upload it there, unpack remotely. It is faster then uploading file by file with ftp.